# How do I convert a cell array of strings representing roman numbers to double?

Tags: matlab, roman-numerals

I am trying to convert a cell array of strings into double so that I can use it.

```
hourNumbers = {'I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X','XI','XII'}

finHourNumbs = cell(1,length(hourNumbers))
for i=1:length(hourNumbers)
finHourNumbs {i} = str2double(hourNumbers{i});
end
```

I get the below output which I am NOT expecting

```
finHourNumbs = 

Columns 1 through 9

[NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]

Columns 10 through 12

[NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]
```

I am expecting it to contain the strings so that I can display.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Any reason why not simply `1:12`, or are you using it as a reference set?

Comment: Any reason for the serial downvoting here?

Comment: @EitanT My question as well. I received two downvotes!

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia I see that all answers here received one downvote.

Comment: @EitanT My mistake. I saw -2 in reputation, thought it is due to two downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/map-containers.html), and create your own `roman2double` like this

```
hourNumbers = {'I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X','XI','XII'};

roman2double = containers.Map(hourNumbers, 1:12);

finHourNumbs = cell(1,length(hourNumbers));
for i=1:length(hourNumbers)
    finHourNumbs {i} = roman2double(hourNumbers{i});
end
```

or in a shorter form

```
hourNumbers = {'I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X','XI','XII'};
roman2double = containers.Map(hourNumbers, 1:12);
finHourNumbs = values(roman2double, hourNumbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on [Gunther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1162609/gunther-struyf)'s solution, you're dealing with a small set of roman numbers that you need to convert to a decimal representation, so you can use a simple conversion. Here's a fast native solution with `ismember`:

```
romans = {'I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X','XI','XII'};
hourNumbers = {'I', 'III', 'XII'}; %// Just a sample input data
[tf, finHourNumbs] = ismember(hourNumbers, romans);
```

The second output of `ismember` is what you need, so just assign it to `finHourNumbs` and presto!

Answer (score 1):

I'd be *very* surprised if any `srt2dbl`-type conversion code recognised Roman numerals. I think you'll probably want to convert them into decimal numbers first.

The `str2double` [doc page](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/str2double.html) states the requirements:

> The string may contain **digits**, a **comma** (thousands separator), a **decimal point**, a leading **+** or **-** sign, an **e** preceeding a power of 10 scale factor, and an **i** for a complex unit.
>
> If str does not represent a valid scalar value, str2double returns **NaN**.

No mention whatsoever of Roman numerals in there.

Answer (score 1):

A [simple google search](http://www.google.be/search?q=matlab%20roman%20numeral%20converter&oq=matlab%20roman%20numer) returns plenty of ways of converting a roman numeral to arabic, of which [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15423-convert-roman-to-arabic/content/roman2arabic.m) seems to be the simplest.

This is just for one string to convert, if you have an array of strings (in a `cell array`), just use a loop or [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
finHourNumbs = cellfun(@roman2arabic, hourNumbers);
```

OR as @EitanT points out, since you're dealing with (a small set of) hour numbers, you can also use a simple conversion array:

```
numsRoman = {'I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X','XI','XII'};
nums=1:numel(numsRoman);
```

and then:

```
finHourNumbs = cellfun(@(str) nums(strcmpi(str,numsRoman)), hourNumbers);
```

Comment: +1, but if you're only dealing with hour numbers, there's no real need for a full translation of roman numerals

Comment: yeah, just a mapping would do just fine in this case, might add that ;)

Comment: I think `ismember` would be more appropriate here

Comment: might be, but I guess it would just do the same thing with some overhead. I'm not bothering adding that solution also..

Comment: Actually I think it would save you the overhead of cellfun+strcmpi, but that was just a suggestion... see my answer :-)